# Cross Platform Python Executable - Mac & Windows?

Tags: python, macos, cross-platform, pyinstaller, python-standalone

I used pyinstaller to create an executable file (Desktop GUI). I am on Windows, and the person I am sending it to is on Mac.

I was under the impression that pyinstaller was cross platform, but the Mac user gets an error when trying to run the app. What are my options for distributing my GUI for both Windows and Mac?

I have not been able to find a straightforward answer and do not have a Mac to test with. I saw [Inno Setup](https://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php), but haven't found anything saying whether or not it's cross platform.

I need to create a script that can run both Windows and Mac. I am also looking for an easy way to send it electronically.

[image]

Comment: Afaik, it's not possible. See [Is there any way to make a dual executable file for Mac/Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1646549/850848)

Comment: I read your link, but I have 0 experience with Mac. Can I just copy the code and compile it on a Mac? Or is it more difficult than that? The GUI relies on wxpython and pandas libraries

Comment: If pyinstaller is creating the executable then that's where you should start - its documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I have no knowledge of Python but after a quick serach on the internet came up with [this](https://www.mytecbits.com/internet/python/installing-python-packages) which might help you.

---

A few months ago I went through this process (rather painstakingly I might add) to deploy a simple Xamarin Cross Platform App. In my own experience I have learned that the **macOS** has very strict rules about how software is to be packaged for deployment on a computer.

If you are using [Visual Studio for Mac](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/mac/) it will automatically build a packaged installer for you. But, you do have to purchase (at an yearly cost) a [Developer ID](https://developer.apple.com/support/developer-id/#:%7E:text=%20Developer%20ID%20%201%20Preparing%20Developer%20ID,Visit%20Developer%20ID%20on%20the%20Apple...%20More%20).

Then, you create specific **provision profiles** for your application and these are used along with your developer ID to [sign](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/signing-in?view=vsmac-2019) your packaged installer. I found it somewhat complicated!

Finally, you follow a procedure via the console on the mac to submit your package for an automatic scan. This is referred to as getting your package [notarized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58600747/mac-notarization-how-to-staple-pkg-file) (link to a SO question about that process).They provide you a result that then gets **stapled** to the package.

It is like a double signing. Once this is done then the package can be installed by users using the macOS.

---

An alternative is that the user run a instance of Windows by using a software package called [Parallels](https://www.parallels.com/uk/). I have to say it is very good and I did enjoy my trial of the software, You can fire up Windows from inside the macOS (no need to reboot) and since it is Windows you can simply run your stahdard installers.

---

In summary, for the macOS, if you do not correctly sign your package with a developer and application ID, and don't get it notarized and stapled the operating system will throw it back out at you and not run it.